# Can myEnum == (A | B) be used instead of myEnum == A || myEnum == B

Tags: c#

If I have :

```
public enum MyEnum
{
    A = 0x01,
    B = 0x10,
    C = 0x100
}

MyEnum MyProp {get; set;}

// ....
```

And I do somewhere :

```
bool isTrue = MyProp == (A | B)
```

I wonder if this can be used as a shortcut for :

```
bool istrue = MyProp == A || MyProp == B.
```

I know that in this context | is the bitwise operator, but I'm wondering how the result will be interpreted by C#. I'm thinking there might be overrides or whatsoever for this particular use case that I've seen used on several places without knowing exactly what the author actually intended to do.

Comment: Why don't you try it?

Comment: I was thinking the same thing 10s ago. It would have taken me less time than writing this question. Let's say I have done it for the community (lol)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Doing a bitwise or on two values each with a different bit set will create a value that has both bits set, so it'll look like `0x011`.  That value is not going to be equal to *either* A *or* B.  It conceptually represents *both* not *either*.

You can use the `HasFlag` method of the enum to determine if a parituclar value has one of the flags set.  So to determine if a particular value has either A or B set you'd need to write:

```
public static bool HasAOrBSet(MyEnum e)
{
    return e.HasFlag(MyEnum.A) || e.HasFlag(MyEnum.B);
}
```

Comment: Also, when creating bit field enums and using HasFlag he should use FlagsAttribute on the enum.